# Remove datalabels from formatter with Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the highchart library and try to display some datalabels with a dinamic format ( using the formatter mecanism).

I need to hide some of the labels, but any try to remove it let the background and the border color visible.

as seen in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ex82/) (They are still some little yellow circles)

**code :**

```
            formatter:function() {
                if(this.y > 150)
                    return this.y;
                else
                    return "";
            }
```

By returning  `""` I set the label empty. I would like it to be entirely hidden but its not.

The question is:
Is there a way to hide some **datalabels** from the **formatter** ?

I know I could set the datalabels enabled or not for each point in the chart initialisation but I need to change it at run time dynamicaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `return ""` with `return null` and datalables wil be correct.

Comment: I was almost sure I already tried it :)  but actually I didn't ^^  thanks it works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/2ex82/1/